# Resque Workers working on the wrong queue

Tags: ruby, background, rake, redis, resque

I have a few Resque jobs running, each started in a separate terminal window like so:

```
QUEUE=queue_1 rake environment resque:work
QUEUE=queue_2 rake environment resque:work
```

Queue 1 started first, then queue 2. The problem is, no matter what QUEUE options I send to new workers, they just keep working on queue 1 -- even if I shut both down. Might this a configuration problem? I haven't seen this issue mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you explicitly setting the ENV['QUEUE'] environment variable in the "environment" or "resque:setup" tasks defined in the Rakefile?